# Find constraint disabled in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraint, alter-table, ddl

I'm doing an audit of constraints in SQL Server.

How to find all constraints that are not enabled?

This, after using the next declaration:

```
alter table mytable nocheck constraint all
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the system views for this:

```
select * from sys.check_constraints
where is_disabled = 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT 
    [object] = QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name), 
    [disabled_constraint] = c.name
  FROM sys.tables AS t
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
  INNER JOIN sys.check_constraints AS c
  ON t.object_id = c.parent_object_id
  WHERE c.is_disabled = 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Mike and Aaron are both on the right track - but the question asks for ALL constraints that are disabled - not just CHECK constraints (i.e., FKs can be disabled too).

Moreover, FKs can also be UNTRUSTED - which will yield the potential for not just bad/invalid DATA but can/will also lead to perf issues (as SQL Server can't/won't trust these FKs when creating execution plans) as per:
https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2007/03/can-you-trust-your-constraints/

As such, I tend to use the following:

```
    WITH constraints AS ( 
    SELECT
        QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.[schema_id])) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) [table] ,
        c.[type_desc] [constraint_type],
        c.[name] [constraint_name]
    FROM
        sys.tables AS t
        INNER JOIN sys.check_constraints AS c ON t.[object_id] = c.parent_object_id
    WHERE
        c.is_disabled = 1

    UNION 

    SELECT 
        QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id])) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME([parent_object_id])) [table],
        CASE WHEN is_disabled = 1 THEN 'FOREIGN_KEY (DISABLED)' ELSE 'FOREIGN_KEY (UNTRUSTED)' END [constraint_type],
        [name] [constraint_name]
    FROM 
        sys.[foreign_keys] 
    WHERE 
        [is_disabled] = 1 OR [is_not_trusted] = 1
)

SELECT 
    [table],
    [constraint_type],
    [constraint_name] 
FROM 
    constraints
ORDER BY 
    [constraint_type], [table];
```

Comment: For further readers; in order to fix the  'untrusted_constraints' you can just rerun adding the constraint, like: `ALTER TABLE [dbo].OrderStatusLogs WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_OrderStatusLogs_Orders_OrderId;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query which lists all constraints from a connected database.

```
select table_view,
    object_type, 
    constraint_type,
    constraint_name,
    is_enforced,
    details
from (
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name] as table_view, 
        case when t.[type] = 'U' then 'Table'
            when t.[type] = 'V' then 'View'
            end as [object_type],
        case when c.[type] = 'PK' then 'Primary key'
            when c.[type] = 'UQ' then 'Unique constraint'
            when i.[type] = 1 then 'Unique clustered index'
            when i.type = 2 then 'Unique index'
            end as constraint_type, 
        isnull(c.[name], i.[name]) as constraint_name,
        c.is_enforced as is_enforced,
        substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1) as [details]
    from sys.objects t
        left outer join sys.indexes i
            on t.object_id = i.object_id
        left outer join sys.key_constraints c
            on i.object_id = c.parent_object_id 
            and i.index_id = c.unique_index_id
       cross apply (select col.[name] + ', '
                        from sys.index_columns ic
                            inner join sys.columns col
                                on ic.object_id = col.object_id
                                and ic.column_id = col.column_id
                        where ic.object_id = t.object_id
                            and ic.index_id = i.index_id
                                order by col.column_id
                                for xml path ('') ) D (column_names)
    where is_unique = 1
    and t.is_ms_shipped <> 1
    union all 
    select schema_name(fk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + fk_tab.name as foreign_table,
        'Table',
        'Foreign key',
        fk.name as fk_constraint_name,
        case when fk.is_disabled = 0 then 1 else 0 end as is_enforced,
        schema_name(pk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + pk_tab.name
    from sys.foreign_keys fk
        inner join sys.tables fk_tab
            on fk_tab.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
        inner join sys.tables pk_tab
            on pk_tab.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
        inner join sys.foreign_key_columns fk_cols
            on fk_cols.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
    union all
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name],
        'Table',
        'Check constraint',
        con.[name] as constraint_name,
        case when con.is_disabled = 0 then 1 else 0 end as is_enforced,
        con.[definition]
    from sys.check_constraints con
        left outer join sys.objects t
            on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
        left outer join sys.all_columns col
            on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
            and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id
    union all
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name],
        'Table',
        'Default constraint',
        con.[name],
        '1' as is_enforced,
        col.[name] + ' = ' + con.[definition]
    from sys.default_constraints con
        left outer join sys.objects t
            on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
        left outer join sys.all_columns col
            on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
            and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id) a
where is_enforced = 0
order by table_view, constraint_type, constraint_name
```